# What's the earliest “acknowledgement” of Heliocentrism in Islam?

Tags: science

The English Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliocentrism) that Heliocentrism was "official" in Christianity in 1822 and in Judaism by the 20th century. What about Islam?

Comment: Where does it say "official"?

Comment: That Wikipedia page doesn't say anything about official positions of entire religions, and there is really no way such a position could ever exist. Nobody speaks for all Christians or all Jews.

Comment: @Daniel, that's why i put "official" in quotation marks. the pope is a significant enough figure to put him as "official" with quotation marks, for the purpose of this question...

Comment: I disagree. The Pope speaks for Roman Catholics. Not Protestants or Orthodox Christians. Also the Rabbi quoted in the article, while influential throughout the Jewish world, is only the leader of a relatively small sect of Jews. In addition, the point he was making was _not_ an endorsement of heliocentricism .

Comment: @Daniel, ok, what do you think about my [summary](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23128/whats-the-earliest-acknowledgement-of-heliocentrism-in-islam/23158#23158)?

Answer (score 2):

Muslim astronomers bestowed great contributions to astronomy. Since Islam was widespread and had many sects we can not talk about an official acknowledged date for heliocentrism. But we understand that Muslim Astronomers may have inspired Copernicus.

> The influence of the Maragha school on Copernicus remains speculative, since there is no documentary evidence to prove it. The possibility that Copernicus independently developed the Tusi couple remains open, since no researcher has yet demonstrated that he knew about Tusi's work or that of the Maragha school.

For more info [Geocentrism_and_Islamic_astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_model#Geocentrism_and_Islamic_astronomy)

It dated back to a few centuries earlier than Copernicus' puplication.

What more impressive idea came from  **Fakhr al-Din al-Razi** was [Multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fakhr_ad-Din_ar-Razi#Multiverse)

Comment: @aasheq mentioned [this (surprising) video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kqv0iuiBta8). How should this video, referencing [36-38](http://quran.com/36/38), be interpreted in the context of your answer?

Comment: I am trying to stand objective. You have your own mind and intellect. If you want opposite point of view of that video you can check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpJmJGh06oA)

Comment: These days i saw a video where it said that Copernicus had copied the Work of [Ibn Shatir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Shatir) [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1K_xAs3FRs). They pretend that in Krakow where he died they found copies of Ibn Shatirs work. Also Copernicus made the same calculation errors ibn Shatir [Arabic Wikipedia](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%B1) did!

Answer (score -2):

(summarizing)

The Quran mentions "astronomy" in verses [21:33](http://quran.com/21/33) and [36:38](http://quran.com/36/38), but these verses are not contradicting or supporting any scientific theory, whether it's geocentrism or heliocentrism.

In other words, it depends on the personal perspective of each and every person. Therefore the "acknowledgement" has nothing to do with Islam or the Quran, but rather with the individual's values.