# Is the sun orbiting the earth according to the majority salafi view?

Tags: islamic-scholar, salafi

In this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXp6v0qRp4c), Sheikh salih al fawzan answers the question; "Does the sun orbit the earth?"

> Without a doubt, this is what the Quran is saying. {Quotes verse 36:38 "وَالشَّمْسُ تَجْرِي لِمُسْتَقَرٍّ لَّهَا"}

He also quoted the verse 2:258:

> When Abraham said, "My Lord is the one who gives life and causes death," he said, "I give life and cause death." Abraham said, "Indeed, Allah brings up the sun from the east, so bring it up from the west."

He then continues explaining that the Quran, says that the Sun is moving, not the earth, and a muslim should not follow theories, a muslim must follow the Quran!

---

I am not sure what Ibn Uthaymen and Bin Baz view was one this, but I heard it was something similar. At least they deny that the earth is rotating as stated in this [article](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=59419). If I am not mistaken, they said they do not make takfir one someone who believes the earth is rotating, which rumors said they did! 
But they say that the one denying that the sun is moving which it says in the quran (36:38) is a kafir (وإنما كفرت من قال إن الشمس ثابتة غير جارية).
*Luckily the sun is moving through the galaxy so there is no need to deny that. <sub>(there are still other ways of interpreting the given verses, so even if the sun isn't moving, we wouldn't need to make takfir one someone who doesn't believe in that)</sub>*

**Is the sun orbiting the earth according to the majority scholars of the salafi view?**

Comment: It will be difficult to gather the opinions of the majority of salafi scholars on this topic to derive a trend, as the topic was not widely debated. Ibn Baz and Al-'Uthamin were clearly wrong in their deduction (the [article](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=59419) you provided mentioned that scholars err as they are human). Ibn Baz published a [response](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/article/472) on his website at the time, where he explained his view, and added that he was not infallible and prone to error as any other human (وليس أحد منا معصوماً).‎

Comment: @III-AK-III Yes I read that response by Ibn Baz yesterday. It is understood that all scholars just are human and prone to error. I do not claim they have said they aren't, I am just looking for the majority salafi view of the scholars who lived since the (majority) scientists agreed on that the sun isn't orbiting the earth.

Comment: This seems related: [What's the earliest “acknowledgement” of Heliocentrism in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23128/17163)